# google.com is not opening in Iframe..Any alternative to open google.com in my application

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to open google.com url in my web application through Iframe but it gives me **"X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"** error and content not loaded issue. Is there any alternative or workaround to do this.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: `alternative or workaround` - no, security is not something you can work around

Answer (score 1):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options for more details.

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a <frame>, <iframe> or <object> .

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/

<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

Answer (score 0):

https://cse.google.com/all use this one instead. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy04EsioLPo This must be something that you are looking for.